# Wrong IndexPath after insertion/deletion of cell from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

### Code

Essentials for the problem parts of VC:

```
// Part of VC where cell is setting
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath) as Cell
    let cellVM = viewModel.cellVM(for: indexPath)

    cell.update(with: cellVM)
    cell.handleDidChangeSelectionState = { [weak self] selected in
        guard
            let `self` = self
        else { return }

        self.viewModel.updateSelectionState(selected: selected, at: indexPath)
    }

    return cell
}

// Part of code where cell can be deleted
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "delete".localized, handler: { [weak self] _, indexPath in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        self.viewModel.delete(at: indexPath)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
    })

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

### Problem

When cell has been deleted and after that `handleDidChangeSelectionState` will be involved then `indexPath` passed into `viewModel.updateSelectionState` will be wrong (will be equal to value before cell deletion).

### I think I know why

1. `IndexPath` is a struct so `handleDidChangeSelectionState` keeps copy of current value (not instance). Any update of original value will not update captured copy.
2. `tableView.deleteRows` will not reload datasource of tableview so `cellForRowAt` will not recall. It means `handleDidChangeSelectionState` will not capture updated copy.

### My to approach to fix that problem

#### * 1st

Ask about indexPath value inside `handleDidChangeSelectionState`:

```
cell.handleDidChangeSelectionState = { [weak self, weak cell] selected in
    guard
        let `self` = self,
        let cell = cell,
        // now I have a correct value
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    else { return }

    self.viewModel.updateSelectionState(selected: selected, at: indexPath)
}
```

#### * 2nd

After every deletion perform `reloadData()`:

```
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "delete".localized, handler: { [weak self] _, indexPath in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        self.viewModel.delete(at: indexPath)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)

        // force to recall `cellForRowAt` then `handleDidChangeSelectionState` will capture correct value
        tableView.reloadData()
    })
```

#### Question

Which approach is better?

I want to:

- keep smooth animations (thanks to `tableView.deleteRows(at: []`)
- find the better performance (I not sure which is more optimal, `reloadData()` or `indexPath(for cell:)`)

Maybe there is a better 3rd approach.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the **1st** approach fulfills the first condition to *keep smooth animations*. Calling `reloadData` right after `deleteRows` breaks the animation.

And calling `indexPath(for: cell)` is certainly less expensive than reloading the entire table view.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use reload specific row, because the index has changed when you delete row, and it will remove animation after deleting row that's why you need to reload `tableview.reloadData()` it is a better option in your case.

```
let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "delete".localized, handler: { [weak self] _, indexPath in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        self.viewModel.delete(at: indexPath)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)

        // force to recall `cellForRowAt` then `handleDidChangeSelectionState` will capture correct value
        tableView.reloadData()
    })
```